# How to populate the values from source tables to destination table in new column based on some condition using pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have 3 dataframes - df1, df2, df3

where df1 is destination table and df2, df3 are source tables.

df2

| id | name | marks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | alex | 30 |
| 2 | john | 70 |
| 3 | jason | 80 |

df3

| id | name | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | alex | fail |
| 2 | john | pass |
| 3 | jason | pass |

and df1 will have following values. ie. I want to fetch status for failed students (from df3) and marks for passed students (from df2) to the df1 with new column named as "status&marks".

| id | name | status&marks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | alex | fail |
| 2 | john | 70 |
| 3 | jason | 80 |

What is the best way to achieve this using pysaprk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join `df2` and `df3`, and then use the `when` function:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df1 = df2.join(df3, ['id', 'name'], "inner")\
            .withColumn("status&marks", F.when(F.col("status")=="fail", F.col('status'))\
            .otherwise(F.col('marks'))).drop('marks', 'status')

+---+-----+------------+                                                        
| id| name|status&marks|
+---+-----+------------+
|  1| alex|        fail|
|  2| john|          70|
|  3|jason|          80|
+---+-----+------------+
```

Comment: Lets say there are null values present in status or marks, then how to use "when" to achieve this?

Comment: You don't have to change anything, it works for nulls too.